# How to reattach DI2 battery mount inside downtube of Canyon Endurace?

Tags: bottom-bracket, shimano-di2

In the process of looking for the charging port for my Canyon Endurace, I stupidly unscrewed the two screws that hold the battery mount to the inside of the frame, because I thought the piece of plastic they were holding on might have been covering up the charging port, and then the battery mount lost contact with the frame so that I cannot screw the screws in again.  Does anyone know how I could reattach this mount without having to remove the bottom bracket?  Is there some sort of trick I could use to get the mount correctly positioned back inside the frame?  How safe is it for the battery to be left loose inside the frame?  How safe is it for a bike shop to remove the bottom bracket?

[image]

Comment: can you get a finger in the bottom access hole and touch the battery?  What about a screwdriver with some sticky tape reverse-wound around the end ?  Might just need to push it up a little until you can get the first screw hole lined up.

Comment: I can't even get a pinky finger in there, not for lack of trying.  I can get a screwdriver in there easily.  I didn't try the sticky tape, but I don't think that would work.  If I had some really long thin pliars, that might though, but I am doubtful.

Comment: If something fell when you removed the screws it's likely resting against the bottom bracket mechanism and could screw it up over time.  Better to open is up and get the stuff out.

Comment: There isn't a junction box at one of the bar ends with a charging port, right?

Comment: @MaplePanda No, I later found out that the charging port is on the derailleur.  I had looked there, but it is well-hidden.  I wish I'd found it there before I tried taking this cover off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main reasonable plan in your situation is just to do it the way it's intended to be done and pull the bottom bracket.

Shimano press fit (and really all press-fit) bottom brackets are prone to getting damaged when removed. Plan on needing a new one.

I'm unfamiliar with the specific bike but I watched [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4U0QbTSWCKs) It appears that the battery change access port is only intended to do anything with the BB removed and is blocked otherwise.

If one were to contrive a way to do it with the BB in, it would probably be something along the lines of dropping the fork and going through the head tube opening to the down tube with a long flexible claw grabby tool such as:

[image]

Part of the problem here is that the battery has some sliding type adjustment in the mount and it will be difficult or impossible to control that positioning without real eyes on it. On some bikes it's necessary to make sure that positioning is just right to avoid clearance/rub/kinking type problems with the wires. On this I can't tell how much of a concern that is, versus working off the assumption that if you can get it all tightened back up and it works you're good. Personally given the expense level of the bike I would want to be able to visually confirm it's really right.

Comment: Thanks.  I've taken it in to a local bike shop to have them remove the bottom bracket and re-secure the battery mount.  Do you know how safe this is for the frame though?  I was a bit hesitant to go this route because that video showed some hammering being done to get the bottom bracket out.

Comment: @kloddant Perfectly safe if done correctly, as you would have to remove it for service anyways.

Answer (score 4):

I did the same thing. Take a deep breath and don’t get frustrated. Get the BB at eye level and pull the plastic cover off. Get a very bright light so you can see well inside. Use something pointed in the screw hole farthest away and position the battery so that you can start the closest screw. Tighten it enough to get the battery lined up. Start the second screw with the plastic cover attached and tighten it up almost all the way. Then pull out the first screw and flip the plastic cover around and restart it through the cover. I was frustrated and fighting it for a while. After taking a deep breath and working smart it wasn’t that hard to do.

Comment: Excellent answer - welcome to the site !

Comment: Randy's answer was spot on - I did the exact same thing and removed the bolts only to find I caused an issue. I was able to use the Shimano di2 tool (small plastic tool) go up under the bottom bracket and hold the position as Randy noted and it worked like a charm. Great advice!